# How do I connect a video card which requires 6 pin PCIE, using a 8pin PCIE port on my PSU?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, sata, pci-express

I bought a second hand pc recently with fairly decent specs, except for the video card, I have a bunch of spare SATA cables dangling(well,tucked away) in my PC but no Molex or PCIE 6 pin plugs.

My power supply is a Be quiet! modular power supply, on which there are multiple 5 pin "HDD" labeled ports(of which 1 in use, goes to sata cables) and 2x8 pin PCIE female plugs. 
I take it the latter is there for powering video cards.
Now, my video card has a 6 pin female PCIE port, and my PSU has a 8pin female PCIE port.
I tried looking on the web but there don't seem to be ready made 6pin male pcie to 8 pin pcie cables for my problem.
I could also use two SATA to molex cables and then a 2x Molex to 6 pin PCIE cable, but this feels like a hack.

Any recommendations or pointers where I can find my solution?

Comment: Some 8-pin connectors are actually 6+2, squeeze it across the diagonal & it may separate. Alternatively, it may fit if you just line up the correct 6 pins.

Comment: Could you supply a picture of the two ends?

Comment: 8 pin should work and the extra 2 will just hang off. If it doesn't fit because there is something in the way when the 2 hang off, then you'll have to get an 8 to 6+2 adapter and only use the 6.

Comment: I ended up buying a 6+2 cable like Tetsujin said, I didn't get it supplied with my PSU since it was second hand, thanks!